# Constructor that takes in a method

Tags: python, constructor

In Python, can a constructor take in a method of another class as an argument?

I've heard that you can do something like this, but this example isn't working (currently, I'm getting a 'module' object is not callable error):

```
class GeneticAlgorithm ():

    def __init__(self, population, fitness, breed, retain = .3, weak_retain = .15 ) :
        self.fitness = fitness
```

Here fitness is a function defined elsewhere and note that I am importing the class where the function is defined.

edit: Here's the code that actually produces the error

```
class Solver( ):

    def __init__( self, fitness, breed, iterations ):

        self.T = Problem()

        self.fitness    = fitness
        self.breed      = breed
        self.iterations = iterations

    def solve( self ):
        P  = self.T.population(500)
        GA = GeneticAlgorithm(P, self.fitness, self.breed) # problem here


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danisg\Desktop\Other\Problem.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\danisg\Desktop\Other\Problem.py", line 124, in main
    t = S.solve()
  File "C:\Users\danisg\Desktop\Other\Problem.py", line 74, in solve
    GA = GeneticAlgorithm(P, self.fitness, self.breed)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

And where the Solver is created

```
def main():
    S = Solver(fitness, breed, 35)
    print(S.solve())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please post the code that actually produces the error.

Comment: For starters:
1.  Your indentation is off (the `def` needs to be indented if its part of the GeneticAlgorithm class).  2.  GeneticAlgorithm should inherit from object.

Comment: In short, yes it can (if a bit iffy due to the `cls`/`self` argument in the method), but we do need the code and error to know why your code is wrong

Comment: Yes, you can pass in a function or method. The "module" error means that you accidentally passed in the module, not a function in the module. Maybe you have a module named 'fred' containing a function named 'fred', then you'd need to pass in `fred.fred`

Comment: Now we know where the problem is, but not WHAT it is. Post the actual error, the stack trace in your console

Comment: The `Problem` class is missing; what does `population(500)` return?

Comment: can you post the code where you create a ``Solver``-instance? (i.e. your call to ``Solver(foo, bar, …)``

Comment: You define `GeneticAlgorithm` as a class, but the error message says it’s a module. No one can debug your code if what you’re running on your computer is completely different from what you are posting here.

Comment: @JoshLee I'm betting he has the class in `GeneticAlgorithm.py` and is just doing `import GeneticAlgorithm`.  It's a common Java-y and PHP-y way to define classes.

Comment: I do `import GeneticAlgorithm'. I should not do this?

Comment: Anyone a suggestion how to retitle this question? Cause it has in fact nothing to do with it's title.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: I'm fine with deleting it. I agree that's its unrelated to the original question and there's a lot on this topic already.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the root of the issue:

> I do `import GeneticAlgorithm'. I should not do this? – gjdanis

No, that's not actually correct.  What you've done is import the module, not the class that's inside the module.  You have two options here - do one or the other:

- Change the import to

  `from GeneticAlgorithm import GeneticAlgorithm`
- Change the Solver class to use

  `GA = GeneticAlgorithm.GeneticAlgorithm(P, self.fitness, self.breed)`

I'd suggest renaming the module from `GeneticAlgorithm.py` to something that isn't quite as confusing (`genetic_algorithm.py` is a good candidate), then using the first option to import just the class from that module - `from genetic_algorithm import GeneticAlgorithm`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could have something like this:

```
def eats_a_method(the_method):
    pass

def another_method():
    pass

eats_a_method(another_method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the stack trace:

```
  GA = GeneticAlgorithm(P, self.fitness, self.breed)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It says `GeneticAlgorithm` is a `module`, not a `function`.